# How to frequently refresh a view without anr?

Tags: android

When I develop a log system in my app，i need to show logs on my view when logs com.
the problem is i will frequently refresh my view at at least 1000ms（1 second).
so it will surely cause android-not-responding as it refresh so frequently.
  how can i frequently refresh my view with great performance?

Comment: What is your use case? Why are you trying to refresh a 1000 times? We could help you better if we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: you can try to put what you want to refresh in a new method of your activity or fragment and just call it 1000 times . also take a local variable like int refreshCount  which will increment every time on your method called and can act as checking condition for that method . and better to call that method in onRestart of your activity or fragment.

Comment: you likely don't need to refresh view so frequently. As well as you will just be unable to due to Android FPS limit, which is 60 FPS in most cases AFAIK. this means that it will refresh your screen not more often than 60 times/sec. So you likely need to add minimal refresh delay for example by storing last refresh time, and checking if some time has already passed before you refresh next time

Comment: so sorry about my poor  description， the 1000 means 1000ms（1s），more specifically，i execute the “notifyDataSetChanged()” method once a second so as to put the newest log on the screen. but when i operate on the screen such as scrolling the ListView, the APP will possiblely anr.

Comment: @bimonthwang One big view containing all your data will redraw very slow. Maybe it will be better to split your data onto list of items and use `RecyclerView`. `RecyclerView` does not keep all items of list in memory, so it can work better on large lists. Also there are multiple graphics libraries like "Glide" if you need graphics in items. If you have troubles with `RecyclerView,` you can post question about it.